# php - how to add all the numbers in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

```
  [
      {
         "total": 71
      },
      {
         "total": 66
      }
  ]
```

How can i sum both numbers up to give me = 137. I have tried array_sum($array_result) but the spits and error saying :

```
array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

this is my code

```
$result = DB::table('marks')->where([
        ['term', $request->term],
        ['subject', $request->subject],
        ['class', $student->class],
        ['arm', $student->arm],
    ])->select('total')->get();

return array_sum($result);

return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Results marked successfully.');
```

Comment: array_sum() accept an array, not an object as explained in the error message. Try to use a for loop on result e sum the values of each key "total"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to sum up `total`, use `sum()` Query Builder method:

```
$result = DB::table('marks')->where([
    ['term', $request->term],
    ['subject', $request->subject],
    ['class', $student->class],
    ['arm', $student->arm],
])->sum('total');
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest to put them in a collection and call [`sum()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum) method.

Like that:

```
$sum = collect($yourArray)->sum('total');
```

You could do it with foreach and a temporary variable as well though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = DB::table('marks')->where([
    ['term', $request->term],
    ['subject', $request->subject],
    ['class', $student->class],
    ['arm', $student->arm],
])->select('total')->get();

 $result = $result->toArray();
```

Now you can simply do this as mentioned by devk

```
collect($result)->sum('total');
```

`get()` return collection. you directly perform actions on collections

like `get()->sum('total')`

I hope this helps.